# Which verb and preposition collocates with the word 'solidarity' in this context?

Tags: collocation

When solidarity exists among members of a group based on ideology and that solidarity gives birth to their allegiance to each other and their allegiance against those who oppose them what verb and preposition collocates with it?

For example: 'The Nazis never (verb) solidarity (preposition) the allies: they were two opposing ideologies.'

A lot of the time 'show solidarity with' is used, but that is usually used to suggest that another group shows a temporary solidarity with another group that is bound permanently by solidarity.

So we might say, 'The British people showed solidarity with the victims of the Haiti earthquake.'

I want the collocation that is used to express the fundamental and permanent solidarity that is an integral part of being a member of a particular group/people/movement, etc.

Comment: Do you really want to use solidarity in that sentence with the Nazis and allies? I don't think any verb or preposition combination can make that a valid sentence. The whole concept of solidarity between factions is kinda opposite to warring factions. Especially in a war on ideology.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Oxford Online Collocation Dictionary](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=solidarity):

> VERB + SOLIDARITY **feel | demonstrate, express, show | foster, promote**
>
> PREP. **in ~ with** *Various other groups of workers went on strike in solidarity with the train drivers.* | ~ **against** promoting union solidarity against management | ~ among/amongst/between *The conflict fostered solidarity among Arab oil states.* | ~ **with** *Orwell expressed his solidarity with the miners in the book.*

Among those, I would say the most pertinent combination would be VERB + in solidarity + with.

> Some of the citizens defiantly wore Stars of David in solidarity with their Jewish neighbors.

Another option is **"cultivate solidarity among/between."**

> When no leader is cultivating solidarity among a people through historical rededication, solidarity can be maintained through cultural institutions.

[[Source](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=NLVCmqUR3ngC&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=%22when+no+leader+is+cultivating+solidarity%22&source=bl&ots=xJDCntJDy4&sig=X1J4Qv3FmVI1LY3QTOwRovbe7-w&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22when%20no%20leader%20is%20cultivating%20solidarity%22&f=false): *Disclosing New Worlds: Entrepreneurship, Democratic Action, and the Cultivation of Solidarity* by Charles Spinosa, Fernando Flores, and Hubert L. Dreyfus]

Answer (score 0):

A rural midwest education taught me that you "feel" solidarity as well as "show" it, so I tend to use the verb "feel" with that word. Solidarity-related concepts tend to be used more with emotionally charged themes, so that's another reason why I gravitate towards using verbs of feeling/sensing.